# Typescript axios typings

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, axios

This is my first question, so let me know how I can improve.

I have the following axios fetch function:

```
export enum RequestMethod {
  GET = 'GET',
  POST = 'POST',
  PUT = 'PUT',
  PATCH = 'PATCH',
  DELETE = 'DELETE',
}

export const fetchAxiosAPI = async (
  url: string,
  method: RequestMethod,
  data = {},
  options = {}
) => {
  let result;
  try {
    result = await axios({
      method,
      url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/${url}`,
      data,
      ...options,
      validateStatus: () => {
        return true;
      },
    }).then(response => response.data);
  } catch (err) {
    return null;
  }
  const errorStatus = result.error.status;
  if (errorStatus === 401) {
    localStorage.removeItem('access_token');
    history.push('/login');
  }
  if (errorStatus === 404) {
    history.replace(NOT_FOUND);
  }
  if (errorStatus === 500) {
    history.replace(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
  }
  return result;
};
```

It looks ugly, uses await and then (which we shouldn't use).
I have two questions:

1. How can I pass a typescript generic into this function as a parameter that will infer typescript typings for the response of API call (Promise)? I found and example using axios[methodName] like:

> axios.get<User[]>(url)

But haven't found a method to pass generic using general axios method like provided in my code example.

2. How to handle error statuses, catch block and await/then - use 1 of them? Basically, how to rewrite `fetchAxiosAPI` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading the documentation and `index.d.ts` file correctly, [`axios.request`](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-method-aliases) should do it. From the docs:

> For convenience aliases have been provided for all supported request methods.
>
> `axios.request(config)`
>
> ...

and in [`index.d.ts`](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/index.d.ts):

> ```typescript
> export interface AxiosInstance {
>   (config: AxiosRequestConfig): AxiosPromise;
>   (url: string, config?: AxiosRequestConfig): AxiosPromise;
>   defaults: AxiosRequestConfig;
>   interceptors: {
>     request: AxiosInterceptorManager<AxiosRequestConfig>;
>     response: AxiosInterceptorManager<AxiosResponse>;
>   };
>   getUri(config?: AxiosRequestConfig): string;
>   request<T = any, R = AxiosResponse<T>> (config: AxiosRequestConfig): Promise<R>;
>   get<T = any, R = AxiosResponse<T>>(url: string, config?: AxiosRequestConfig): Promise<R>;
>   delete<T = any, R = AxiosResponse<T>>(url: string, config?: AxiosRequestConfig): Promise<R>;
>   head<T = any, R = AxiosResponse<T>>(url: string, config?: AxiosRequestConfig): Promise<R>;
>   options<T = any, R = AxiosResponse<T>>(url: string, config?: AxiosRequestConfig): Promise<R>;
>   post<T = any, R = AxiosResponse<T>>(url: string, data?: any, config?: AxiosRequestConfig): Promise<R>;
>   put<T = any, R = AxiosResponse<T>>(url: string, data?: any, config?: AxiosRequestConfig): Promise<R>;
>   patch<T = any, R = AxiosResponse<T>>(url: string, data?: any, config?: AxiosRequestConfig): Promise<R>;
> }
>
> export interface AxiosStatic extends AxiosInstance {
>   create(config?: AxiosRequestConfig): AxiosInstance;
>   Cancel: CancelStatic;
>   CancelToken: CancelTokenStatic;
>   isCancel(value: any): boolean;
>   all<T>(values: (T | Promise<T>)[]): Promise<T[]>;
>   spread<T, R>(callback: (...args: T[]) => R): (array: T[]) => R;
>   isAxiosError(payload: any): payload is AxiosError;
> }
>
> declare const axios: AxiosStatic;
> ```

Notice that `request` just accepts the config object like the `axios` function itself does, but unlike `axios` it has the generic type parameters you've seen used on `get`, `post`, and such.

So something like this, see `***` comments:

```typescript
export const fetchAxiosAPI = async <T>(
//                                 ^^^−−−−−−−−−−− *** type parameter
    url: string,
    method: RequestMethod,
    data = {},
    options = {}
) => {
    let result: T;
    try {
        // *** Get the response using `axios.request` with the type argument
        const response = await axios.request<T>({
            method,
            url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/${url}`,
            data,
            ...options,
            validateStatus: () => {
                return true;
            },
        });
        // *** Get the result
        result = response.data;
    } catch (err) {
        return null; // *** This is poor practice; allow the error to propagate
                     // or throw a new error
    }
    const errorStatus = result.error.status;
    if (errorStatus === 401) {
        localStorage.removeItem('access_token');
        history.push('/login');
    }
    if (errorStatus === 404) {
        history.replace(NOT_FOUND);
    }
    if (errorStatus === 500) {
        history.replace(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
    return result;
};
```

Comment: Thanks, turns out I need to use axios.request. Is it good practice to wrap my function with tr/catch block?

Comment: @MindaugasN - The function *call*, yes, or the call to the function that calls it, or the one that calls that, etc. You don't want to hide the fact an error happened from those other functions, or force them all to check return values. Instead, have a single error handler at the highest possible level (typically the event handler or similar that started the call chain).